# I'm using htmlagilitypack to extract some data from a website but I can't figure out what issue happen?

Tags: c#, xpath, web

```
string Url = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/browse/dvd-all/?services=netflix_iw";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load(Url);

foreach ( var node in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body[@class='body  ']/div[@class='body_main container']/div[@id='main_container']/div[@id='main-row']/div[@id='content-column']/div[@id='movies-collection']/div[@class='mb-movies list-view']/div[@class='mb-movie']"))
{
    string movieTitle = node.InnerText;
    richTextBox1.Text += movieTitle + System.Environment.NewLine;
}
```

I want to extract all movies title from this URL navigating XPath. VS says that I have no object reference. Why? Can you try for me in this particulary case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following piece of code worked for me:

```
string Url = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/browse/dvd-all/?services=netflix_iw";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load(Url);

IEnumerable<string> movieTitles = from movieNode in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                                  where movieNode.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("movieTitle")
                                  select movieNode.InnerHtml;
```

It uses LINQ to access the nodes containing the movie title.

Comment: can you explain me what exactly did you do in the linq query? I don't know XPath so I'm glad if you explain me. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @CRK I'm accessing nodes having `class=movieTitle`. All these nodes are `<h3>` HTML elements and they contain the movie title. Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes! It works fine for me too. Last question: why you leave the second parameter in movieNode.GetAttributeValue("class", "") blank? and what if a node not have the "class" parameter? LinQ skip it?

Comment: I notice another thing: in the web page there are more than the first results that the linq query returns because there is a button "Show More" in the web page that shows other movies. How can I track all 380 movies in the page and not only the firsts?

Comment: can u help me??